# Using OpenStreetMap tiles in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap, arcgis-9.3

I was hoping to use ESRI's ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap to view OpenStreetMap data in ArcMap, but my organization hasn't upgraded to version 10 yet.

I also know about ArcBruTile, but I prefer not to use that software because of the potential TOS violations with Google, Bing, etc.

Does anyone know of another way to bring OpenStreetMap tiles into ArcGIS 9.3.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSM Layers for ArcGIS

http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=b834a68d7a484c5fb473d4ba90d35e71

Alternatively *http://osm.wheregroup.com/ have a WMS OSM Server (Europe)

```
    Data Type: WMS Service 
WMS Server: http://osm.wheregroup.com/cgi-bin/osm_basic.xml?SERVICE=WMS&version=1.1.1&service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&layer=Grenzen&format=image/png&STYLE=default&
Service Name: OSM_Basic
```

Default Coordinate System:
GCS_WGS_1984
Datum: D_WGS_1984
Prime Meridian: 0

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Arc2Earth claims to be able to import OpenStreetMap (as well as Google imagery and maps) into ArcGIS. Unlike ArcBruTile which is buggy and barely legal (if legal at all), it is my understanding that Arc2Earth is completely legit but not free.

Scratch that, there is a free version; In terms of just trying out the OpenStreetMap tiles there is a "Free" version but as it indicates on the site the map tiles will be watermarked.

Separate "Data Service" is required if you want Google Imagery capabilities within ArcGIS.

http://www.arc2earth.com/products/desktop/

Comment: Looks like they are out of business :/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at 
"[Adding Openstreetmap to ArcGis 9.3.1](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/14129/adding-openstreetmap-to-arcgis-931/22286)" and "[Can you use OpenStreetMap tiles in ArcGIS 9.3.1?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10563/can-you-use-openstreetmap-tiles-in-arcgis-9-3-1)" topics, the only solution easy to use seems to be [ArcBruTile](https://bertt.itch.io/arcbrutile) but not free (25 euros) otherwise you should consumes WMS services build with OpenStreetMap data (some in the second provided topic). There is a mention of an Arc2Earth product but the company has been closed.