# How to serve OpenStreetMap Tiles locally using ArcGIS Server 10?

Tags: raster, arcgis-server, openstreetmap, leaflet, maperitive

We want to serve OpenStreetMap Tiles locally using ArcGis Server 10 to use as base maps in our ESRI Silverlight and Flex GIS clients.

We've downloaded our regions OSM file and created PNGs using [**Maperitive**](http://maperitive.net/) for Zoom 1 thru 18 and tested with [**Leaflet**](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/).  Also used a script to generate PGW files for each PNG.

Is this goal possible, should we use raster datasets or something different ?

Comment: related: OSM as base layer - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10563/can-you-use-openstreetmap-tiles-in-arcgis-9-3-1

Comment: @ajayel: how did you generate the PGW-files? could please explain this. thanks

Comment: hi @kurt we took advice from [JustKez.com](http://www.justkez.com/mapnik-openstreetmap-rasters-in-arcgis/) and then vb.net code [from Ben Freeman](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/462146/Georeferencing-Open-Street-Map-Tiles-to-Use-with-M)